# How to prevent a listview from adding a blank line?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, blank-line

Currently this is my code.

```
        TextReader reader = new StringReader(richTextBox1.Text);
        string[] strItems = null;
        while (reader.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string nextRow = reader.ReadLine();
            if (!listView1.Items.ContainsKey(nextRow.GetHashCode().ToString()))
            {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                item.Name = nextRow.GetHashCode().ToString();
                strItems = nextRow.Split("-".ToCharArray());
                item.Text = strItems[0].ToString();
                try
                {
                    item.SubItems.Add(strItems[1].ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
                try
                {
                    item.SubItems.Add(strItems[2].ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
                try
                {
                    item.SubItems.Add(strItems[3].ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
                try
                {
                    item.SubItems.Add(strItems[4].ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

It add's Items from a textbox to a ListView, but if there is a Blank line in the textbox it also adds a blank item to the listview. I am looking for a way to stop this from happening. All help is appreciated.

Comment: empty catchs are the root of all evil.

Comment: you can replace `"-".ToCharArray()` just with `'-'`

Comment: Also, you can avoid duplicating code using `for(var i=0;i<5;i++) item.SubItems.Add(strItems[i].ToString());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an if to check that:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextRow)) {
   execute the code you need
}
```

Comment: By the way string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace should take care of white space